# Unable to import Google Test metrics in Sonarqube

Tags: xslt, tfs, sonarqube, googletest, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 (update 2), C++, Google test and Sonarqube 5.6 (with Cxx community plugin).
I am able to import the coverage, compute duplication, create issues using cppcheck but the number of tests is not importing in sonarqube.

I need to generate a Junit-like XML file using `<test executable> --gtest_output=xml:<filename>` but in TFS (vNext), I use the [VSTestTask](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTest/README.md) which uses vstest.console.exe to run my *Test.exe and there seems to be no way to output as xml (it defaults to .trx).

Has anyone managed to correctly import GTest test metrics into sonarqube? Is a XSLT to transform from trx to xunit the only way...?

May be i need to properly fill in the `sonar.cxx.vstest.reportsPaths` but the filename of the trx is dynamically set by the vstest.console.exe...

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put `**/TestResults/*.trx` in `Visual Studio Test Reports Paths` (`sonar.cxx.vstest.reportsPaths`) and now it is being loaded correctly... go figure.

Comment: Yes, .trx is supported by default. According to you description "I need to generate a Junit-like XML file  ", I was misunderstanding that you just want a .xml test result report.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is a little bit old but I got the same problem than you to import gtest test report into SonarQube.

I've finally found a [converter](https://github.com/RedPaladin/sonar_test_report_converter) that transforms a gtest test report to the [Generic Format](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-test/). It supports also junit xml format but I did not test by myself. The original script was made by another guy, bloodle, but I forked his repository to migrate to Python 3. All the thanks go to him.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is converting the test result to XML format. After that you just used the default import functionality.To achieve this, use CoverageCoverter.exe with below code.

```
class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if ( args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Coverage Convert - reads VStest binary code coverage data, and outputs it in XML format.");
                Console.WriteLine("Usage:  ConverageConvert <sourcefile> <destinationfile>");
                return 1;
            }

            CoverageInfo info;
            string path;
            try
            {
                path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(args[0]);
                info = CoverageInfo.CreateFromFile(args[0], new string[] { path }, new string[] { });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error opening coverage data: {0}",e.Message);
                return 1;
            }

            CoverageDS data = info.BuildDataSet();

            try
            {
                data.WriteXml(args[1]);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Error writing to output file: {0}", e.Message);
                return 1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

More detail info and ways please refer [Publishing vstest results?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/jenkinsci-users/pipeline/jenkinsci-users/TRX5U4yULC8) & [MSTest Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin)

Comment: thanks for the xsl but it actually seems *.trx are natively supported. the path i had put in was incorrect.